# Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(); return null

Tags: java, xml

I have a problem with my current fonction :

```
public static Connection ConnectDB(){
        try{
        File fichier = new File("\\XFiles\\Conf\\init.xml");
        System.out.println(fichier.getAbsoluteFile());
        String nom = fichier.getName();
        InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(nom);
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(input));
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        String url = (String) xpath.compile("//init//jdbc//url").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
        String driver = (String) xpath.compile("//init//jdbc//driver").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
        String username = (String) xpath.compile("//init//jdbc//username").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
        String password = (String) xpath.compile("//init//jdbc//password").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);   

        String passwordCryp = String.valueOf(password);

        Cryptage cipherUtil = new Cryptage();
        String mdpCrypte = cipherUtil.encrypt(passwordCryp);

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); //méthode qui retourne la classe de l'objet assoccié au string
        if(conn==null){ //si la connexion est null
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+"integratedSecurity=true;",username,password); //récupérer les informations de la connexion (serveur, BDD...)
            logger.debug("Connexion Réussite");
        }

        return conn; //retourne la connexion
        }catch(Exception e){ //s'il y a une erreur
            logger.error(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I compile and run it, the variable 'input' is always null. I've tried to put the xml file in a File object, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` is for reading resources from the classpath, not for reading files from the file system. Where is your XML file really located, and why do you think using `getResourceAsStream` is the right approach? Maybe you need to use a `FileInputStream` instead.

Comment: Finnaly I used DOM to resolve my problem and it works. THank you.

Answer (score 1):

`String nom = fichier.getName();` will only return the filename, which is `init.xml`. If you want to access the file in the path you specified you should use `fichier.getPath()` or even `fichier.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: If I use ```fichier.getPath() + fichier.getName()``` it will only concat the path (which containt the name of the file) and the name file. So I will be something like this : ```..\...\init.xmlinit.xml``` . So.. I don't think it could work

Comment: sorry, my mistake. `getPath()` or `getAbsolutePath()` should be sufficient